# Blazor Server .Net Core Authentication linking to other database tables

Tags: authentication, .net-core, blazor

So I'm new to .NET Core and **Blazor (server)** and if you use the built-in authentication **(I'm using SQL Server)**, you end up with a bunch of user tables in the database.

I want to create relationships with tables unrelated to either Authentication or Authorisation, linking the user to the other tables. In the user table we have a choice of Id `nvarchar(450)` and `UserName nvarchar(256)`

Now coming from a world where I would have just an Integer-based auto Id, I'm struck by two things

1. even if Microsoft wanted a guid, why an nvarchar(450)?
2. why is the email address / username not encrypted by default?

So what field is everyone using to link to other tables?

I've just seen an example using the email field and I'm just imagining the GDPR fallout from that, so surely the Id field has to be the way to go, but doing all my relationships on a nvarchar field of that length seems really weird to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. even if Microsoft wanted a guid why an nvarchar(450)

The length may seem a bit arbitrary but [SQL server has a max key size of 900 bytes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122000/why-sql-server-has-900-byte-index-size-limit).
That comes down to 450 unicode chars.

So it basically is an "we made it as long as possible, you can use it as you like" kind of offering.

The *var* in nvarchar means a key only occupies as much space as is actually needed, 450 is the *max* length. Changing it to for example an nvarchar(36) would save you zero space and time.

In theory you could use something else than a string/nvarchar, like `class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>` but that would ripple out through a lot of related classes. And I know that `string` is nailed down for TKey in some library parts so you would have to replace those. A lot of work.

> 2. why the is the email address / username not encrypted by default.

Encryption in/by your app would be of little use, where would you store that encryption key? If GDPR is a concern then you can configure encryption at the database level where it belongs.

But when you want to go DIY, the relevant columns are marked with `[PersonalData]` , you could hook in on that.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, that at least does explain why the length is the way it is, I think working with the Id field is the most sensible way to go.

I understand what you are saying about the encryption and I guess making it open ended is sensible, and I agree if given the option using Always Encrypted or similar at server level would be my first choice, but sometimes I'm on a shared hosting platform where that isn't possible.

Comment: Well, ASP.NET Identity is widely used in ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core, you can google what is customary.